# How can I trigger a method on property change?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a class tabBarController and every time its selectedIndex property changes, I want to trigger a custom method. How do I accomplish this?

this is how the tabBarController is being declared in the h's instance vars:

```
BaseViewController *tabBarController;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use UITabBar's  `-(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem * )item` method to determine the index of the tab and consequently the method you wish to call.

Comment: more details cab be found here.    http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITabBarDelegate

Comment: Does this go in m file for the class that implements the UITabBarControllerDelegate protocol?

Comment: I applied that method, but it's not being fired. Could my tabBarController have a different parent class? its declared as BaseViewController *tabBarController;

Comment: Have you set `self.myTabbar.delegate = self`?

Answer (score 3):

This is a perfect candidate for key-value-observing.  Basically, when the value is changed, a notification is fired off and picked up by any `observers` that you define that want to be observing that value for any changes. When you establish yourself and an observer and implement the `observeValueForKeyPath:` method, you can have it fire off whatever method you would like.

Here is a good starting point: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000177-BCICJDHA

A little daunting at first, but basically magic when used properly.

Edit: didn't see that it was simple a `UITabBarController`.  Yes, simply use the delegate methods. KVO is overkill for this.

Comment: In general, KVO is great, but if a delegate method is available, it's much easier to set up.

Answer (score 0):

Create a setter:

```
- (void)setSelectedIndex:(NSInteger*)integer
{
    // Do stuff
    selectedIndex=integer;
    // Or: [super setSelectedIndex:integer];
}
```

Comment: Do I need to create a subclass to use this setter? Where does it go?

Answer (score 0):

Use `delegate` method `-(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem * )item`